# Rename method Soap with xslt

Tags: xslt, soap, wsdl, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to rename a SOAP method with XSLT but i didn't got it yet

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:unk="http://unknown.namespace/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <unk:sum>
             <arg0>1</arg0>
             <arg1>2</arg1>
          </unk:sum>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i want to get this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:unk="http://unknown.namespace/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
    <unk:multiply>
        <arg0>1</arg0>
        <arg1>2</arg1>
     </unk:multiply>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

On the other hand i am trying to consume a web service renaming by hand the method with soap UI and get this error:

```
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Unexpected wrapper element {http://unknown.namespace/}multiply found. Expected {http://unknown.namespace/}sum.</faultstring>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `multiply` method defined in the WSDL?

As for the transformation in the SOAP envelope, you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:unk="http://unknown.namespace/">

    <xsl:template match="unk:sum">
        <unk:multiply>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </unk:multiply>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template matches the node `<unk:sum>`, replaces the tag and recursively processes the child nodes, running any templates matched for the nodes encountered. The second template recursively copies all other nodes with attributes.

Comment: That xslt doesnt rename the ´<unk:sum>´ tag, now i have the two tags:
<unk:multiply><unk:sum>
<arg0>5</arg0>
<arg1>4</arg1>
</unk:sum></unk:multiply>